# How to alter a main menu link path programatically drupal 7?

Tags: 7, navigation

In my case, My site URL is www.example.co.uk and also have a content page www.example.co.uk/bbc.

There is a menu link called **BBC** with *https://www.bbc.co.uk* under my **menu menu** menu link list. I can change the link from backend but how I alter that link-path programmatically?

I want to change "www" depending on sites, like if it's on test site then the link should be ***wwwtest.bbc.co.uk*** or in develop then ***wwwdev.bbc.co.uk*** .

Comment: It's simple, do not add the domain name to your link path. Don't do absolute path `wwwtest.bbc.co.uk/home` simply do what is called a relative path `/home`.

Comment: Thanks, @NoSssweat , but in my case, I don't want to make any changes on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_menu_link().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
  $element = !empty($variables['element']) ? $variables['element'] : array();
  if (!empty($element['#title']) && $element['#title'] == 'BBC') {
    $url = $variables['element']['#href']; 
    $url_parts = parse_url($url); 
    $path = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . $url_parts['path']; 
    $options = array();
    foreach (array('query', 'fragment') as $part) {
      if (!empty($url_parts[$part])) {
        if ($part == 'query') {
          $option = drupal_get_query_parameters(drupal_get_query_array($url_parts[$part]));
        }
        else {
          $option = $url_parts[$part];
        }
        $options[$part] = $option;
      } 
    }
    $variables['element']['#href'] = url($path, $options);
  }
}
```